# This in function inside object Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, this

what is the wrong in this code , function fullAdress
i don't know what is the wrong in my code,
help my to fix it

```js
var person = {
 firstName: 'Ammar',
 lastName: 'Gais',
 age:21,
 adress:{
  street:'king road',
  city:'atabra',
  state:'River Nile'
  fullAdress: function(){
   return this.street+" "+this.city+" "+this.state;
  }
 },
 fullName: function() {
  return this.firstName+" "+this.lastName;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your question is about `this` in `fullAdress` but you don't appear to use `fullAdress` for anything. You also have a typo (missing `,`) which prevents your code from compiling. You need to include an [mcve] and a *clear problem statement* (which a vague description of [something being "wrong"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't).

Comment: also address (with two "d") is the correct english spelling

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after `'River Nile'`. It is always recommended to look at the browser console for such errors. Even the object has properties or methods, everything should be separated by comma:

```js
var person = {
  firstName: 'Ammar',
  lastName: 'Gais',
  age: 21,
  adress: {
    street: 'king road',
    city: 'atabra',
    state: 'River Nile',
    fullAdress: function() {
      return this.street + " " + this.city + " " + this.state;
    }
  },
  fullName: function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}

console.log(person.adress.fullAdress());
console.log(person.fullName());
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. **If you delete this answer, the OP will be able to delete their question**.

Comment: The question is about the use of `this` in the function. The typo seems to be an error writing the question and not what the question is about.